# Make a very simple CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making an extremely simple CMS with rails that simply changes existing text and images on existing pages, nothing else. No changes to layout or anything crazy like that.

It's a bit like wordpress. Here's how it'll work:

- If an admin is logged in, they have a special bar at the top of the
  page that will enable them to edit the page.
- Upon clicking, they go to the control panel, and all of the editable regions of viewable.
- They can then edit the pages in the control panel, and save it.

**What would be a good way to organize this flow?**

I've made a start, and one thing that gets me is that all of the logic that populates a page' editable regions is occurring in the view:

*splash/welcome.html.erb*

```
<% @page = Page.find(name: 'welcome') %>
<% regions = @page.text_regions %>

<h1> <%= regions.where(name: 'title').text %> </h1> This returns the title (Welcome to my website)
<%= regions.where(name: 'welcometext').text %> This returns welcome text (This is my website bla bla)
```

I works fine, although the database has to be initially seeded with empty regions.

However, I don't like how there is logic in the view, so how could I populate a `@regions` instance variable in the application controller? Or is what I'm doing fine?

Maybe in the future I want users to be able to create pages, meaning I won't be able to have this logic in the view.

Answer (score 0):

**DRY**

Looks like you'd be better using [`action_name`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController/Base:action_name) (perhaps with a helper)

Without knowing the structure of what you're trying to do, this is just speculation, but you may be better doing something like this:

```
#app/models/region.rb
Class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :title,        -> { find_by name: "title" }
   scope :welcome_text, -> { find_by name: "welcometext" }
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_page

   private

   def set_page
       @page = Page.find_by name: action_name
       @regions = @page.text_regions
   end
end

#app/views/shared/_regions.html.erb
<h1><%= @regions.title.text %></h1>
<%= @regions.welcome_text %>

#app/views/static/welcome.html.erb
<%= render "shared/regions" %>
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas as to how to achieve what you want?

Comment: See Docu: All scope methods will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object which will allow for further methods **(such as other scopes)** to be called on it.

find_by return Object or nil:

Try to "Region.title.welcome_text"

it doesn't work.

Comment: ideally title and welcome_text should be relations with a lambda scope on page

Comment: @RichPeck "find_by_name(blah) has been deprecated in favor of "where(name: blah).first" this is why Rails 4 needs deprecated_finders gem if you keep them http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

Comment: Dave, thanks for the update! `find_by` is still very much in the Rails documentation - http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by - `find_by_x` has been depreciated, yes :)